# When using single vert to do molding, when I apply the skin and subdiv mods I can’t edit the verticals or faces of the mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

I can’t edit the verticals on the mesh on the single vert after applying the skin and subdiv mod it only shows two verticals once on top and bottoms but how do I get the dots all over the surface of the mesh

Comment: You can't because faces and edges don't actually exist until you've applied the skin modifier. Suggest you watch Joey Carlino's [YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAAwy_l4jw4) on modelling with the skin modifier.

Comment: How do the guys on YouTube do it that way? Is it something they not showing us

Comment: I guess you don't mean "applying" but rather "giving"? Maybe show a screenshot

Comment: As @moonboots says, show a screenshot (via Window > Save Screenshot and loading it into your question) and possibly upload your blend file to https://pasteall.org/blend/ so that we can see your object.